# What may be the reason of a MATLAB Standalone Application not working?

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I have an application that designed in MATLAB and a couple of scripts (.m files) that are required for my application to run. The working principle of the application is that it reads a MS Excel file, do calculations and gives another Excel file as ouput. I want to use this application on target machines that do not have MATLAB installed. However, the standalone application that packed by using MATLAB Compiler, isn't running the scripts and returns an error sound. The steps taken are as follows:

1. Application Compiler Project started
2. The application file, with .mlapp extension, chosen as main file
3. The script files, required for my application to run, added automatically
4. Packing process of the Standalone Application completed at Compiler where MATLAB runtime also included in package
5. The current folder, now also including an "app Installer" file for redistribution,  deployed to the target machine
6. A compatible MATLAB Runtime installer file also deployed into the folder
7. "app Installer" file executed and a Standalone application created where MATLAB runtime also installed simultaneously

I followed those steps but the application isn't running the scripts. To determine the error, I ran the exe file through the dependency walker, and it shows the following error:

LAUNCHERMAIN.DLL -- Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2).

What may be the reasons behind this problem?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: What does “returns an error sound” mean? What do the error messages say?

Comment: Deleting the answer by byildirimacwa left this question in a strange state. His problem is apparently solved and no further answers are required.

Answer (score 0):

Three things that can help:

`diary`  - add a diary to application so you can see what errors are thrown

`lasterror` - have a menu item which captures the lasterror output and provides the info in a graphical way to help you figure out the problem

`cmd`  - run the exe from DOS prompt on **most** systems the matlab terminal output is printed to the DOS terminal window, but I have seen some cases with windows 10 and recent Matlab versions where this very useful feature doesn't work, dont know why.